# New to C, trying to read file from command line and store its contents (of ints) into an array. Then run my program using that array.

Tags: c, arrays, command-line, file-read

New to C, trying to read file from command line and store its contents (ints) into an array. Then run my program using that array.

I originally ran this program with user input like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void clear(void);

int main(void)
{
int * pointerGrades;
char x = 'y';
int grade = 0;
int count = 0;
int i = 0;
int input = 0; 

//setting up my pointer array
pointerGrades = malloc(sizeof(int) * 11);

for ( i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    pointerGrades[i]=0;
}

//what do I need from user to run this program
printf("You can enter in grades here, and can input as many as you want.\n");
printf("Please only use scores from 0 to 10.\n");
printf("To exit grades type a number greater than 10, like 11 or 12.\n\n");

//having the user input the grades
while ( grade >= 0 && grade <= 10)
{
    input = 0;

    //checking to see if they put in an int or something they shouldn't
    while(input !=1 )
     {
        //asking for the int
        printf("Student %d: Score 0 to 10.\n", count+1);
        input = scanf("%d", &grade);
        clear();
     }
     //student#
     count++;

     //adding grade score
     pointerGrades[grade]++;

}


//printing grades out
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    if( i % 5 == 0)
        printf("\n");

    printf("Scores of [%d]: %d\t", i, pointerGrades[i]);
}

free(pointerGrades); //clearing the array when done

return(0);
}

//clears my buffer so my loop doesn't keep running, forever, like it is.
void clear (void)
{
    int ch; while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' &&  ch != EOF );
}
```

But now I'd like to run this program on the command line so that I can get a little more practice with it. I want to create a file and take the contents of the file and put it into a buffer to read, and then use its contents to run my original program. I obvously have no clue what I'm doing at this point I think I've stared at it way too long. I've read multiple posts on how to pull a file on the command line, but haven't found anything on how to then use the information the way I'm hoping to.

This was originally a hmwk assignment with user input. I'm now just trying to use it on the command line reading a file instead.

The original assignment:
[ Generate a text-based histogram for a quiz given to a class of students. The quiz is graded on a scale from 0 to 10. Write a program that allows a user to enter grades for some number of students. As the grades are being entered, the program should count, using an array, the number of 0’s, the number of 1’s, the number of 2’s, the number of 3’s, the number of 4’s, and the number of 5’s. The program should be capable of handling an arbitrary number of student grades (that is to say we do not know how many grades will be entered until the user wishes to stop entering grades).You can do this in part by making an array of size 11, where each array element is initialized to zero. Whenever a zero is entered, increment the value in the array at index 0. Whenever a one is entered,
increment the value in the array at index 1, and so on, up to index 10 of the array.]

Any help or criticism is welcome, I'm here to learn and anything is better than nothing. Thank you!

This is what I have so far for my attempt at command line file read:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define BUFSIZE 25

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
/* the first command-line parameter is in argv[1] 
   (arg[0] is the name of the program) */
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); /* "r" = open for reading */

int buffGrades[BUFSIZE]; /* a buffer to hold what we read in when we call the file */

//setting up my pointer array
buffGrades = malloc(sizeof(int) * BUFSIZE);

char x = 'y';
int input = 0; 
int grade = 0;
int count = 0;
int i = 0;


for ( i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    buffGrades[i]=0;
}

/* read in one line, up to BUFSIZE-1 in length */
while(fgets(buffGrades, BUFSIZE - 1, fp) != NULL) 
{   

    while ( grade >= 0 && grade <= 10)
    {   int input = 0; 
        int grade = 0;
        int count = 0;

     //student#
     count++;

     //adding grade score
     buffGrades[grade]++;

    }


    /* buff has one line of the file, do with it what you will... 

    printf ("%s\n", buff); /* ...such as show it on the screen */
}

//printing grades out
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    if( i % 5 == 0)
        printf("\n");

    printf("Scores of [%d]: %d\t", i, buffGrades[i]);
}


free(buffGrades); //clearing the array when done
fclose(fp);  /* close the file */ 

    return(0);


  }


//clears my buffer so my loop doesn't keep running, forever, like it is.
void clear (void)
{
    int ch; while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' &&  ch != EOF );
}
```

Comment: at 1st version `pointerGrades[grade]++;` occurs out of bounds when last input (because grade > 10).

Comment: You can use `fscanf` and `fgetc`.

Comment: What is the question? If you have a problem, please post a minimal example and ask about that specific problem. If you want general code review of working code, there is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I would like to run the first program on the command line using a file of input vs user input and I have no clue how to make that happen. I provided my original code for user input and then my attempt at command line file read, but I cannot get it to work.